# What are "Alternate Minimums"?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, flight-planning, instrument-procedures

As I asked [question about weather minimums](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24548/is-there-any-difference-on-landing-minima-between-icao-and-faa) yesterday, I've read some material including TERPs. And In the FAA 8260.3b, 'Taking and Landing Minimims' 3.1 there is one sentence "alternate minimims, when specified, must be stated as ceiling and visibility."

But I don't know What alternate minimums exactly means because I am not native English speaker. I have used English dictionary to find exact meaning but failed.

What is the difference between approach minimums and alternate minimums?

Answer (score 10):

[FAR 91.169](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFar.nsf/FARSBySectLookup/91.169) states that IFR flight plans must include an *alternate airport* unless the weather is at least 2000 ft ceiling and 3 miles visibility, from one hour before to one hour afterwards (*1-2-3 rule*).

The same regulation also states that the alternate airport must meet the following critera:

> (c) IFR alternate airport weather minima. Unless otherwise authorized
>   by the Administrator, no person may include an alternate airport in an
>   IFR flight plan unless appropriate weather reports or weather
>   forecasts, or a combination of them, indicate that, at the estimated
>   time of arrival at the alternate airport, the ceiling and visibility
>   at that airport will be at or above the following weather minima:
>
> > (1) If an instrument approach procedure has been published in part 97
> >     of this chapter, or a special instrument approach procedure has been
> >     issued by the Administrator to the operator, for that airport, the
> >     following minima:
> >
> > > (i) For aircraft other than helicopters: The
> > >       alternate airport minima specified in that procedure, or if none are
> > >       specified the following standard approach minima:
> > >
> > > (A) For a precision approach procedure. Ceiling 600 feet and visibility 2 statute miles.
> > >
> > > (B) For a non-precision approach procedure. Ceiling 800 feet and visibility 2 statute miles.

Comment: So, Do you mean that 'alternate minimums' means alternative aiport's minimum? If yes, Does the word 'alternate' imply 'alternative airport'?

Comment: Yes the forecast weather for the alternate airport must be above minimums.

Comment: More precisely, it must be well above minimums, and have an instrument approach.

Comment: It doesn't have to be well above anything except what's written above. There are plenty of approaches that are 800/2. And since the alternate minimums are below basic VFR of course it has to have an instrument approach.

Comment: Also, some procedures aren't eligible for use as an alternate approach.

Comment: That would make an excellent answer to a question about selection an approach at an alternate

Comment: ...And some approaches have non-standard minimums for their use as an alternate.  It is also possible for an airport with no instrument approach to be used, provided forecast weather allows for descent from the MEA to the airport under basic VFR.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between APPROACH minimums, and ALTERNATE minimums:

APPROACH minimums are stated on each approach plate, for instance, 200 ft. ceiling with 3 mi.  visibility.  It's a real-time minimum, because it only affects whether or not you can begin that particular instrument approach.  On arrival, you check the airport's weather (METAR, for instance) and if the real weather is reported better than the required weather for a particular approach, then you can begin that approach.  Therefore, you need to take the destination weather forecast into account when planning.

ALTERNATE minimums affect your PLAN, even BEFORE you take off, and is not related to approach minimums.  An "alternate" refers to a second airport you identify in your planning that you can go to if the weather at the destination turns too bad to land.  The thinking is that, if the weather at the destination is FORECASTED to be good around your arrival time (an hour before til an hour after), then you shouldn't need to list an alternate airport in your flight plan.  Generally, the destination's weather has to be FORECASTED more than 2,000 ft. ceilings and 3 miles visibility, or if not, you have to IDENTIFY an alternate destination airport in your flight plan.  The FORECASTED weather at the ALTERNATE airport has to be better than a certain ceiling / visibility, too.  You have to look at the approaches available at the alternate to know what the minimum requirements are there.  If the alternate airport has a "precision" approach (for instance, an ILS), the FORECASTED weather at the ALTERNATE has to be at least 600 ft. ceiling and at least 2 mi visibility, otherwise you can't list it as an alternate.  But airports with a non-precision approach (for example, a VOR-A approach) require better  conditions with 800 ft. ceilings.

Answer (score 0):

I found an excellent article about it at [IFR Magazine](http://www.ifr-magazine.com/issues/1_3/features/Alternate-Alternatives_24-1.html).

Basically, to qualify as an alternate airport, the alternate must have certain forecast weather conditions (600-2 for precision approach, 800-2 for non-precision.) These are the "alternate minimums".

However, those are just the default values. Many airports have different values, in which case the alternate minimums will be published on the approach plate (example: [PAO VOR approach](https://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/1913/09216V31.PDF), top-left, next to the inverted 'A')