# What can disqualify an airport to be used as an alternate?

Tags: faa-regulations

As a military pilot, our regulations listed things that disqualified airports as being alternates.  I have not been able to find a reference to these same items listed in the 14 CFR Part 91.  Does anyone know where to find the regulatory references for the list of things that disqualify an airport as an alternate for an IFR plan?  For example, an airport cannot be used as an alternate if the instrument approach at the airport you plan to use is listed as "Radar Required."  Is that a consideration in General Aviation?  Likewise, I was trained that if a navaid is unmonitored or if the airfield only has GPS approaches, again disqualifies the airfield as an alternate.  However, I don't know where that is written in the FARs.  Does anyone know where I should look?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are "Alternate Minimums"?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24580/what-are-alternate-minimums)

Comment: There are part 91 rules, 121 rules, and 135 rules for alternate requirements.  Are you asking for non-commercial (91), scheduled carriers (121), or charter (135)?

Comment: I was thinking part 91, but the more I research this topic, I'm beginning to think that I'm suffering from "negative transfer."  It looks like I've brought something from my military training that doesn't necessarily apply to Part 91 operations.

Answer (score 5):

**As far as Part 91 ops go, paragraph 91.169 is the only IFR alternate requirement to my knowledge.**

*Unless otherwise authorized by the Administrator, no person may include an alternate airport in an IFR flight plan unless appropriate weather reports or weather forecasts, or a combination of them, indicate that, at the estimated time of arrival at the alternate airport, the ceiling and visibility at that airport will be at or above the following weather minima:

(1) If an instrument approach procedure has been published in part 97 of this chapter, or a special instrument approach procedure has been issued by the Administrator to the operator, for that airport, the following minima:

(i) For aircraft other than helicopters: The alternate airport minima specified in that procedure, or if none are specified the following standard approach minima:

(A) For a precision approach procedure. Ceiling 600 feet and visibility 2 statute miles.

(B) For a nonprecision approach procedure. Ceiling 800 feet and visibility 2 statute miles.

(ii) For helicopters: Ceiling 200 feet above the minimum for the approach to be flown, and visibility at least 1 statute mile but never less than the minimum visibility for the approach to be flown, and

(2) If no instrument approach procedure has been published in part 97 of this chapter and no special instrument approach procedure has been issued by the Administrator to the operator, for the alternate airport, the ceiling and visibility minima are those allowing descent from the MEA, approach, and landing under basic VFR.*

**If you look in the front of the approach book (DOD or JEPP) it will list the 600/800' limitation for alternate designation.  I guess it's not in the UPT syllabus because the 11-214 (and the DOD for that matter) doesn't honor that specific alternate limitation.  FAR Part 135/121 ops might list other limitations that look like the "RVSM reqd, Wx reporting, GPS only, etc.)

-the queep monster....**

Comment: Thanks I've considered all of those possibilities.  In addition to 91.169 which you've included, I've research Part 97, Order 8260.3C (TERPS rules), the Instrument Flying Handbook, Aeronautical Information Manual, and several CFIs with YouTube channels.  None of which I've seen in the  Part 91 side ever goes into these disqualifying items.  It appears to me that the main reference for the A/NA as a disqualifier is in the legend for terminal procedure charts.  Again, I think I brought something over from my military training that doesn't apply to Part 91.  Regardless, thank you for your help.