# If the airport reported BKN002, would that prevent performing a DH 259' approach?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, approach, icao

According to this Instrument Approach:

The published Minimums are a Visibility of 1300 m, and a DH of 259 feet.

In accordance with ICAO, would the Visibility and Ceiling be above the Published Minimums to be able to execute the approach or only the Visibility?

For example, if the airport reported **BKN002**, would that prevent from performing the approach?

[image: ILS]

On this approach, Jeppesen explicitly states ***"CEILING REQUIRED"***, would that Mean that Both Visibility and Ceiling (Broken or Overcast) must be met to execute the approach?

[image: ILS SBAO]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any difference in landing minima between ICAO and FAA?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24548/is-there-any-difference-in-landing-minima-between-icao-and-faa)

Comment: Which ICAO documents, should I refer to to answer my question?

Comment: what's the airport please?

Comment: @ymb1 The first one seems to be SKBG, Palonegro, Colombia. The second one looks like SBGL, Rio de Janeiro, Brazil. (I searched for BGA and GAVUG, respectively).

Answer (score 1):

Since you ask about ICAO, I have checked ICAO's PANS-OPS and Manual of All-Weather Operations.

"Ceiling Required" is **not** an ICAO term.

Since you tagged one of the plates SBAO (a Brazilian FIR; Atlantico ACC), I found a blog post from 2017, *[Brazil drops Ceiling requirement](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/brazil-drops-ceiling-required-arnold-pieper).* From which, only 10 countries use that term, and ICAO hasn't used it since 1979 when PANS-OPS (8168) was released. My only guess is that your Jeppesen screenshot predates this 2017 change (the copyright says 2016).

You need to refer to the local [AIP](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Aeronautical_Information_Publications_(AIPs)) if this term is used locally.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, for ILS the only limiting thing would be visibility/RVR. For Non precision approach, you will need to worry about the ceiling. Ceiling Required above would be for a LOC approach which is a Non precision approach.